# Display the article list in the front end in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi How can i display the list of articles in the front end Joomla 2.5. I am new to the 
Joomla 2,5 [image]Please help me ? I changed the Layout option as list but it does not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are listing from one category just use the Category List menu type and select the appropriate category.

http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help16:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Category_List

e.g.

[image: creating an article list from a category]

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want using menu then use query in your custom page :-

```
<?php
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT id, title FROM #__content WHERE state = '1' ORDER BY ordering";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
<select id="s_articles" name="s_articles">
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) {?>
<option <?php if ($row->id == $value) { echo " selected=\"selected\""; } ?>value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" >
<?php echo $row->title;?>
  </option>
<?php }?>
```